# How can I sort the y-axis in Ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the below code:

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_classic())

g <- ggplot(EYAnmut_3rdParty, aes(QuestionNumber))
g + geom_bar(aes(fill=stemmed), width = 0.5) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6)) + 
  labs(title="Histogram Plot")
```

Which provides this plot:

[image]

How can I sort the Questions in the Y-axis to be in ascending order (smallest to largest) ? At the moment, it looks very scrambled.

The structure of my dataframe looks like this:

[image]

I tried changing the structure of my QuestionNumber variable to factor but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question to remove image data. Add data using `dput`

Comment: The `y` axis is count. I assume you want to sort the `fill` axis

Comment: The fill axis (which is "stemmed") is actually comprised of the values "Yes", "No" and "Maybe". I am thinking that sorting this would not be helpful. Please let me know if it's otherwise.

Comment: @Dinesh use `dput(head(df,20))` to add data to your question.

Comment: @Nelson, I'm trying my best to add in dput(), but it's still slightly confusing me.

Comment: When you run `dput(head(Data,20))`. Copy whatever it outputs and add that to your question.

Answer (score 1):

With no sample data, an illustration is made using the famous iris: It can be assumed that Species is question number.

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  arrange(desc(Species), Sepal.Length) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fct_rev(fct_infreq(Species)), Sepal.Length, fill=Species)) +
    geom_col() +
    labs(x="Species")
```

Comment: This is possibly another variant answer. I'll need to check on this.

Comment: You should add data to your question for a more precise answer. The logic is no different though.

Answer (score 1):

```
Data$QuestionNumber <- ordered(Data$QuestionNumber, 
                                           levels = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7","Q8","Q9","Q10","Q11","Q12","Q13","Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17"))
```

This code worked for me. I re-ordered the column based on levels.